# Indexable objects in newest typescript compiler version (0.9.5)

Tags: javascript, typescript

After updating to 0.9.5 I've found some errors in the defenition for js-library.
Let me explain the situation through the code. 
It is my JavaScript code:

```
var Sample = lib.ClassImpl({
    ctor: function(array) {
        var me = this;
        this._items = array;
        this._items.forEach(function(name) {
            me[name] = new ItemWrapper(name); //Implemetation of ItemWrapper is unnecessary
        });
    },
    doSomething: function() {
        //some logic
    },
    returnSomething: function() {
        return this._items.length;
    }
});
```

And this is the usage:

```
var sample = new Sample(["First", "Second", "Third"]);
sample.doSomething();
console.log(sample.returnSomething());
console.log(sample.First.method());
console.log(sample.Third.method());
```

In typescript defenitions which I've wrote for previous version of TypeScript compiler (0.9.1.1) I was able to do:

```
export interface ISampleBase {
    doSomething(): void;
    returnSomething(): number;
}
export interface ISample extends ISampleBase {
    [name: string]: ItemWrapper; //here is the error
}
export class Sample implemets ISampleBase {
    constructor(array: string[]);
    doSomething(): void;
    returnSomething(): number;  
}
```

And then use it in my ts-file (intellisense works like a charm):

```
var sample: ISample = new Sample(["First", "Second", "Third"]);
sample.doSomething(); 
sample["Third"].method();
```

But after update to version 0.9.5 I've got an error, that all named properties must by subtypes of string indexer type ItemWrapper on line above that marked by comment. 
Is there any variants for me to resolve the issue?

[TypeScript playground with example.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=interface%20ISampleBase%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20doSomething%28%29%3a%20void;%0A%20%20%20%20returnSomething%28%29%3a%20number;%0A%7D%0A%20interface%20ISample%20extends%20ISampleBase%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bname%3a%20string%5D%3a%20Date;%20//here%20is%20the%20error%0A%7D%0Adeclare%20class%20Sample%20implements%20ISampleBase%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%28array%3a%20string%5B%5D%29;%0A%20%20%20%20doSomething%28%29%3a%20void;%0A%20%20%20%20returnSomething%28%29%3a%20number;%20%20%0A%7D)

Comment: So I'm wondering what you ended up doing since this is no longer legal.  I have Similar issue with d.ts file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to express this anymore in TypeScript. This is such an inherently dangerous pattern (e.g. what happens when I pass `["doSomething", "returnSomething"]` to that constructor?) that it wasn't worth supporting the complexity of rules around what string indexers otherwise meant.